# How does Spring Boot really use Apache Commons Logging given I don't see a dependency to it from Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, apache-commons-logging

I see in the Spring Boot [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) that,

> Spring Boot uses Commons Logging for all internal logging...

However when I search for a (maven) dependency to [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/) from Spring Boot artifacts I don't see any dependency references to it.

Does Spring Boot use a separate internal fork perhaps of [Apache Commons Logging](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/)? or am I missing something?

I couldn't find much in this connection online. Does someone know & can help share pointers?

Below for example is the dependency tree for `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.0`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< dcm.dev.util:maven-dependency-resolver-tool >-------------
[INFO] Building maven-dependency-resolver-tool 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ maven-dependency-resolver-tool ---
[INFO] dcm.dev.util:maven-dependency-resolver-tool:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.11:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.32:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.17.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.36:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.30:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.13.3:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.63:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:39 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-13T13:40:38-06:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks

Comment: Look here `org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.20:compile`.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Thank you for that pointer! So it looks like the documentation (the logging part I referred above) needs an update to say that Spring Boot uses Spring Commons Logging, which btw [appears](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20611#issuecomment-453462024) indeed to be a kind of fork of Apache Commons Logging.

Comment: @K.Nicholas Please feel free to answer & I can mark accordingly (in case someone else comes along & misses the comments). Thanks once again for your time!

Comment: It uses the Commons Logging API but it has been included in Spring itself for various reasons. The reason for this is [in the original issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19081?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel). So it is still the Commons Logging API (You could even include it if you like).

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum for that additional link with more details on the team thinking that went into the fork. I certainly don't want to include Apache Commons Logging at all, quite the contrary I want to avoid packaging that as some customers don't prefer old libraries being packaged. Btw, as I mentioned in the [above](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/20611#issuecomment-453462024) comment it might help to correct the documentation to note (at the least) the fact that Spring uses Spring Commons Logging which is forked from Apache Commons Logging & only uses its API.

Comment: As Spring depends on the API it will need it and it isn't Spring COmmons Logging it is still Apache Commons Logging.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your response, but just to clear my confusion, my understanding of Spring Commons Logging comes from seeing references to it [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/spring-jcl.html) & [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jcl) and it made sense aswell given the discussion in the two git issue links referred above that went into the change. If we are to say otherwise (that it is still Apache Commons Logging) then the above 2 may need correction...

Comment: Below is why I am not convinced we can say it is still Apache Commons Logging,
1. Apache Commons Logging artifact is technically _no longer a dependency_ from spring's core artifacts/starters (as we have forked out to `spring-jcl`) & is _not needed_ to run Spring apps.
2. While the API may have been retained in the fork (due to considerations discussed/noted in git issue links) the underlying implementation is not the same as noted [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/19081?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel#issuecomment-453442669)

Comment: The API is still the commons logging API, hence it still is commons logging. All classes, frameworks etc. that use commons logging can use `spring-jcl`. From an API perspective this is still Apache Commons Logging (that is my approach to things, the API is still the same). The only reason to keep the API the same is binary compatibility (moving to SLF4J would have changed the signatures).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, I see where you are coming from now from a dev/eng perspective. Only nuance here is unlike pure API specs (like JTA/JPA) which are deployable via their respective artifacts with chosen implementation (BTM/JTA, Hibernate/JPA) here we are talking about the bound API of commons logging where in there is no _contract_ whatsoever that, 1. A future change (however unlikely it is) made in commons logging's API would be adhered to in `spring-jcl` & 2. `spring-jcl` would not have its API modified _in the future_ in any way so as to 'break' the API _contract_ of commons logging.